# get value that already chosen before, while running the update function

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

my registration page have multiple DropdownButton inside, while i'm running the update page how can i get the DropdownButton value that already chosen, in case i only want to update one of them. so i don't need to re-input all of the DropdownButton's value...

here is the DropdownButton code inside registration page

```
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('employee').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            const Text("Loading.....");
          else {
            List<DropdownMenuItem> employeeItems = [];
            for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
              DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.documents[i];
              employeeItems.add(
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    snap['employee'],
                  ),
                  value: snap['employee'],
                ),
              );
            }
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                  ),
                  DropdownButton(
                    items: employeeItems,
                    onChanged: (managerValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectemployee = managerValue;
                      });
                    },
                    value: selectemployee,
                    isExpanded: true,
                    hint: new Text(
                      "Choose Manager",
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),




RaisedButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text(isEditMote ? "Update" : "Save"),
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                try {
                  if (isEditMote) {
                    Reg reg = Reg(
                      manager: selectemployee,
                      id: widget.reg.id,
                    );
                    await FirestoreService().updateEmp(reg);
                  } else {
                    Reg reg = Reg(manager: selectemployee);
                    await FirestoreService().addEmp(reg);
                  }
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                }
              }
            },
          )
```

any help would be appreciated.. :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to store the already chosen data in a variable inside a stateful widget. But your question is hard to understand and no way to test your code as it will pulled from a larger app and is not standalone testable.

Comment: @kent here is the full source code https://github.com/learnAndro/flutter